# Trigger on case Email-To-Case

Tags: trigger, case, email2case, entitlements

This is my trigger

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (Before Insert, Before Update) {

  for(Case c:trigger.new){
  
    if(c.ContactId == null && c.AccountId == null){
        c.AddError('*****Error');
    } 
    else if (c.Origin == 'Email'){
        Group SupportTeam = [Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' 
                             AND Name = 'Support Team' LIMIT 1];
                             c.OwnerId = SupportTeam.Id;
        List <Entitlement> entls = [Select e.StartDate, e.Id, e.EndDate, 
                                    e.AccountId, e.AssetId 
                                    From Entitlement e
                                    Where   e.AccountId=:c.AccountId And 
                                    e.EndDate >= Today And 
                                    e.StartDate <= Today];
        if(c.EntitlementId == null ){
          for(Entitlement e:entls){
            c.EntitlementId = e.Id;
            if(c.AssetId==null && e.AssetId!=null)
              c.AssetId=e.AssetId;
              break;
            } 
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

When I send an email to the email-to-case address, the case is created but the entitlement is not associated to that case. However when I manually create a new case the entitlement is added to it.
Can you please help me ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SFSE! An Entitlement would be tied to an Account or an Asset with which it would be assigned to a Case being created. Are you sure that Account/Asset is being populated when a case is created via Email-to-Case.

Comment: Hello, yes the account is populated when a case is created via Email-to-case

Comment: In your trigger you are populating the Asset Id as well... Is Entitlement mapped to an Asser or Account. If an Account is populated and considering it is mapped with an Entitlement, hope the Date is in align to current date and it is active. If an entitlement is mapped while creating manually but not via code, most probably the issue would be with the fields that we are populating would make the difference... Just to test you can clone the record that has been created via trigger to see if an Entitlement is added to that record.